# Trouble initializing less stylesheets on my meteor app

Tags: meteor, less

My less style sheets are located in my /public folder for now. I'm trying implement them on my meteor app but to no avail.

This is the error I get:

[image]

The stylesheets are located in the /less folder, which is inside the public folder, so the URL should be correct. By the way, all those files that are in the screenshot above are files that import dozens of other variables located deeper in the folder.

I also checked and I have the latest version of less installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `public` folder isn't the right place to store the files. Files stored in a “public” folder are served to visitors. These are files like images, favicons, and the “robots.txt” file. So they get served 'as-is', not processed by LESS and served as CSS.

[More about Meteor folder conventions](http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/structure/).

Comment: I just placed them in public temporarily to see if the stylesheets would be rendered. It's usually in the stylesheets folder on client. URL is shorter when I place it in public...but of course when it's production it won't go in public folder.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek they will not be compiled at all in the public folder, less files need to be out of public, even on your local...

Comment: @FloatingCoder can I ask you what the correct absolute URL would be if my less stylesheets were located in the /client/stylesheets/less folder? Would it be http://localhost:8000/client/stylesheets/less/? Because nothing works at this moment.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek You should not need the path to the less files, they are compiled and included by Meteor, or at least they should be. If I do a search in the chrome devtools sources tab for a class from my less file I can find it in merged-stylesheets.css, as well as under /app/<path-to-original-file> but I can not access it directly due to the router. With the files in /client/stylesheets/less are you seeing the errors? Are you missing the styles? Are you trying to include the less files yourself somewhere?

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek, possibly a dumb question, but do you have the less package installed? It should be listed in .meteor/packages

Comment: @FloatingCoder Yep, I have latest version of less installed. I'm trying to link 4 less files via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="filename.less">`. These 4 less files contain code that imports variables from less files seeded deeper in the less folder. I try to place the code in my template file, but I get the error above. I tried placing it in client, then public, then back to client. I tried all types of URLs and nothing works.

Comment: @MabehAl-ZuqYadeek you don't need to manually link to the stylesheets. Meteor finds your LESS files anywhere in the project, compiles them all and merges into a single CSS file which is then automatically put in <head>.

Answer (score 1):

After discussion in the comments, it seems something is not working right in your less compiler, the less file should not be in the public folder, as already mentioned, and you should not need to include it with a script tag. You can follow these steps to create a new app and test less and see if you can find a difference between this and your current app.

1. Create a new meteor project

   ```
   meteor create test
   ```
2. Add less

   ```
   cd test
   meteor add less
   ```
3. Start your server

   ```
   meteor
   ```
4. add a file sytles.less to the top level folder with this...

   ```
   .fun {
       color: red;
   }
   ```
5. Update the test.html file to add the fun class to the text output...

   ```
       <div class="fun"><p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p></div>
   ```
6. Load the page, the text should pick up the class and become red. No link to the styles.less file needed. You can try moving it around to different folders, it worked fine from client for me as well. Look around and see what else might be different.

If you still have issues, try providing more information on how the project is set up.